# can I find the kernel version in system logs

Tags: kernel, system, versions, logs

I am developing a new debugging technique bc my ubuntu crashes. I had this idea of running with older kernels and see if they behave better/worse. I know how to find kernel version using a command. What I like to know if there is a message written in system logs showin g the kernel version. And if there is no version written in the logs, I would strongly suggest that it is put in. Namely after boot, the first line would say this is kernel 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP, or whatever.
thank you for listening

Comment: You mean like the fourth line in `journalctl`?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel version is written to the file `/var/log/dmesg`.

The information is written into the third line.

Example:

```
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 2.6.24-16-server (buildd@palmer) (gcc version 4.2.3 (Ubuntu 4.2.3-2ubuntu7)) #1 SMP Thu Apr 10 13:58:00 UTC 2008 (Ubuntu 2.6.24-16.30-server)
```

Comment: BTW: for this to work you need sudo permissions.